# Android Studio: Bottom Navigation View - AAPT: error: ' ' is incompatible with attribute drawable (attr) reference

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview, material-components, material-components-android

I have added BottomNavigationView in my application like.

**main.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_bgcolor"
    app:itemIconSize="50dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_colors"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_colors"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_items">
</com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```

**menu/nav_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_white"
        android:title="@string/nav_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_market"
        android:icon="@drawable/market_white"
        android:title="@string/nav_market" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_news"
        android:icon="@drawable/news_white"
        android:title="@string/nav_news" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_account"
        android:icon="@drawable/account_white"
        android:title="@string/nav_account" />
</menu>
```

**drawable/nav_bgcolor.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="#FF9800" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="#FFFFFF" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

**color/nav_item_colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#FFFFFF" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="#727272"/>
</selector>
```

this is the preview in the android studio

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yICxFcTbSxYpILDtxg75Z4x-2Y1UaPM_/view?usp=sharing

it is actually displaying the design that i want to happen.

there is no error or something but when i run the app there are errors in **drawable/nav_bgcolor.xml**

```
C:\Users\[PCNAME]\AndroidStudioProjects\[APPNAME]\app\src\main\res\drawable\nav_bgcolor.xml:3: AAPT: error: '#FF9800' is incompatible with attribute drawable (attr) reference.
C:\Users\[PCNAME]\AndroidStudioProjects\[APPNAME]\app\src\main\res\drawable\nav_bgcolor.xml:4: AAPT: error: '#ffffff' is incompatible with attribute drawable (attr) reference.
```

the error happened after i added **app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_bgcolor"** in the **main.xml**

I have searched the internet but no luck in getting any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your selector you are using

```
<selector>
    <item android:drawable="#FF9800" android:state_checked="true" />
```

You can't use a color (`#FF9800`) where you should define an `android:drawable`.

Use

```
<menu>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_add"
        android:title="@string/nav_home" />
    ...
</menu>
```

where `icon_add` is a simple drawable.
And in your `BottomNavigationView`:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_colors"
     ../>
```

Comment: So i need to create a drawable resource with a solid color #FF9800 then use it in the drawable selector?

Comment: @troidevera what is your final purpose? You would like a icon tint with a selector?

Comment: I just want to change the itembackground color of the selected item with color orange when selected. I am done changing the icon tint and text color when selected with no errors even after running but not the itembackground coz there is this AAPT error.

Comment: this solved my problem. thanks sir @GabrieleMariotti.

Comment: Just wanna ask another one. Because i'm adding android:background in bottomnavigationview in main.xml but it is not applying in the design. I am adding a drawable background by the way. Can't i apply both app:itembackground and android:background at the same time? Coz when i try to remove app:itembackground, the android:background is showing.

Comment: @troidevera Exactly. `itemBackground` and `android:background` can't work together. Inn the default style  there is  
`<item name="android:background">?attr/colorSurface</item>`
`<item name="itemBackground">@null</item>`

Comment: Ahh is that so. But what default style? Is that the style.xml in values folder? What exactly will i do to create and use android:background? Will i just insert it in the style name:AppTheme or create a new style name? Sorry i really dont know how to do that. I'm really new in app development.

Comment: Quite complex to explain themes and styles in a comment. You can start from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Owkf8DhAOSo&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_xXXubDti2eRnIKU0p7wHd&index=50&t=0s).

Answer (score 0):

**replace android:drawable with android:color in  drawable/nav_bgcolor.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#FF9800" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="#FFFFFF" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Comment: No. It is used as icon in the menu. It works with a drawable not a color selector.